# Laravel appending accessor unexpectedly also add relationship to response

Tags: php, laravel

Thank you for taking time to help me understand this issue.

I have a 'Vehicle' class like the following:
(to keep i simple i removed alot of methods and fillables)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Trip;

class Vehicle extends Model
{
    public $fillable = [
       ...
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'LastTrip'
    ];

    public function trips()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Trip::class);
    }

    public function getLastTripAttribute()
    {
        return $this->trips->last();
    }
}
```

The issue is that when i return a instance of this class from a controller.
It serializes the 'trips' relationship, so that every trip is in my response.

This however only happens when i try to append the 'LastTrip' accessor.
If I change it to the following, the issue doesn't persist

```
protected $appends = [
    #'LastTrip'
];
```

I'm only trying to get it to serialize the 'LastTrip' accessor.

I hope i made my issue clear, and please let me know if i can apply any futhere information.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you also show the response?

Comment: @tamrat The response is long and included all the different properties.
But i hope it helps
https://pastebin.com/z0BjnETq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

When you call `$this->trips->last()`  it fetches all trips and then assigns the last to LastTrip. But if you use parentheses after 'trips' it has to get only 1 row from db, try this:

```
public function getLastTripAttribute()
{
    return $this->trips()->latest()->first();
}
```

or

```
public function getLastTripAttribute()
{
    return $this->trips()->orderByDesc('id')->first();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I can see my mistake now

Comment: You are welcome) also see IGP's answer, he checks if relation is already loaded, I think in this situation it won't be loaded in advance, but you can try it in other situations needed

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your accessor does the following:

1. Load the full trips relationship
2. set the last item from the trips collection as last_trip attribute.

Change your code to the following:

```php
public function getLastTripAttribute()
{
    // If the relation is already loaded, avoid doing an extra SQL query
    if ($this->relationLoaded('trips')) {
        return $this->trips->last();
    // Otherwise, get the last trip from an SQL query.
    } else {
        return $this->trips()->orderByDesc('id')->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you for taking time to help me solve this